# Получить количество записей в таблице базе данных, используя ООП технологии PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Подскажите оптимальный способ узнать количество записей в таблице базы данных **MySQL** при помощи **ООП** (**PHP**).

Comment: Вам не кажется что кол-во записей в MySQL не имеет отношения к стилю написания кода на PHP, хоть ооп хоть функциональный код, способ будет одинаков.

Comment: Подскажите оптимальный способ узнать температуру воздуха при помощи отвёртки (с чёрной ручкой).

Comment: Откалибровать отвертку есть чем? если найдется инструмент для калибровки, думаю сможем решить вашу задачку :)

Comment: > Подскажите оптимальный способ узнать
> температуру воздуха при помощи
> отвёртки (с чёрной ручкой).

По аналогии с вычислением высоты с помощью барометра:  
откручиваем термометр у соседа,  
продать отвёртку и купить градусник  :)

Comment: а по-моему, парень  просто привел в качестве вопроса какую-то институтскую задачку. По крайней мере, стиль формулировки вопроса выглядит именно так

Comment: @DreamChild: ну это же не повод, чтобы не поприкалываться?

Answer (score 5):

ООП говорите) [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) вам в помощь!

Comment: О, правильно, доки рулез!

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'root',
    '',
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tbl";
  $cnt = $pdo->query($query);
  echo $cnt->fetch()['total'];
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```